# Why does my program not progress to the next class?

Tags: java

The program shows the output for only "A" class which is 10. 
But why does the program not advance to the class "B" whose answer should be 12?

```
interface ConstInterface {
    int MAX=10;
}

public class A implements ConstInterface {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(MAX);
    }
}

class B  {
    int MAX=12;
    void maxNew(){
        System.out.println(MAX);
        B obj = new B();
        obj.maxNew();
    }
}
```

Comment: The real question here is: Why do you think it should?

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose You're right. I understand that the program ends when main() returns. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program ends when `main()` returns. You have no code in `main()` that calls anything in class `B`. That's why the program "does not advance".

You could change this by moving the two lines

```
B obj = new B();
obj.maxNew();
```

out of the `maxNew()` method in `B` and putting them inside `main()`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(MAX);
    B obj = new B();
    obj.maxNew();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Java for standalone application the starting point of execution is public main method in a class which in your case is class A.

To also execute maxNew of class B you should create object of B in main method and invoke maxNew method.

Try modified code below :

```
    interface ConstInterface {
    int MAX=10;
}

public class A implements ConstInterface {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(MAX);
    B b = new B();
    b.newMax();
    }
}

class B  {
int MAX=12;
void maxNew(){
System.out.println(MAX);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The lesson here :computers do exactly what you tell them to do. For Java programs that is determined by the content of the *main* method. And your main does not contain anything that would make use of your *B* class.